# MVVM Binding to Foreign Key Property in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm getting started with Entity Framework and need some help understanding the functionality between two Tables. To start with I have `PhoneRecords` and `PhoneModels`. Each `PhoneRecord` has a property called `PhoneModelId` that relates to one of the `PhoneModels`. In MySQL these properties are setup as a foreign key relationship.

Now I've loaded a sample of `PhoneRecords` into a `DataGrid`. I have a `TextBox` that I want to reflect the model on the `PhoneRecord`. At present my `TextBox` looks like so:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SelectedRecord.PhoneModelId}"/>
```

and, unsurprisingly, the `Id` is displayed instead of the `Name` of the `PhoneModel`. Usually without EntityFramework I would just have a property on the `PhoneRecord` itself called `PhoneModelName` or something similar which I would get using a `JOIN` when writing out my `SELECT` commands..

It seems to me that that method is old fashioned, and that Entity Framework is a powerful tool for getting around writing long CRUD operations. However, I am stuck in seeing how I am able to bind in MVVM to the `PhoneModel` name rather than using the `PhoneModelId` property on the `PhoneRecord`.

Comment: If your model reflects the database, you could create a related property on your `PhoneRecord` called `PhoneModel` and EF will populate this if you tell it to, e.g: `var records = context.PhoneRecords.Include("PhoneModel")` and in your binding you would `{Binding SelectedRecord.PhoneModel.Name}`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
"{Binding SelectedRecord.PhoneModel.Name}"
```

I'm not sure which version of EF you're using or which flavour (code-first, DB first, code-first with existing database, etc.)... but...

In EF if you have an object that has a foreign key relationship it will attach that object to it's parent or child. So each PhoneRecord will have a PhoneModel object attached to it, and vice versa. If you're using code first, you'll have to code this relationship, if you're using DB first it should already exist int the model (EDMX) and you should be able to navigate to a PhoneModel from a PhoneRecord and back again.