# MVVM Foreign Key Property in Entity Framework and show in DataGrid

Tags: wpf

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509697/mvvm-binding-to-foreign-key-property-in-entity-framework) I have got two tables one is Article and the other is Familia.
which I'd try to show Related Field of the table. let's look.

```
public partial class Article
{
    public int IdArticle {get; set;}

    public string CodeArt {get; set;} = null!;

    public string DescArt {get; set;} = null!;

    public string CodeFamilia {get; set;} = null!;

    public virtual Familia? CodeFamiliaNavigation {get; set;} 
}
```

and

```
public partial class Familia
{
    public string CodeFamilia {get; set;} = null!;

    public string DescFamilia {get; set;} = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; } = new List<Article>();
}
```

this is my ArticleViewModel

```
public class ArticleViewModel
    {
        public List<Article> ListArticles {get; set;}
        public ArticleViewModel()
        {
            fillList();
            
        }

        private void fillList()
        {
            using (EmployeeContext context = new EmployeeContext())
            {

                ListArticles = context.Articles.ToList();
            }
        }
```

now lets look at my window

```
  <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ArticleViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
   <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgArticle" Margin="15 40 10 10" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListArticles}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="CodeArticle" Binding="{Binding Path=CodeArt}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="DescArticle" Binding="{Binding Path=DescArt}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="CodeFamilia" Binding="{Binding Path=CodeFamiliaNavigation.DescFamilia}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

here in the DataGrid third column I follow the answer for that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509697/mvvm-binding-to-foreign-key-property-in-entity-framework). there is nothing to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you load the related entities? Try this:

```
private void fillList()
{
    using (EmployeeContext context = new EmployeeContext())
    {
        ListArticles = context.Articles.Include(x => x.Familia).ToList();
    }
}
```